# Can operations be generalized?

Tags: c#

I just wrote this code:

```
private double PerformOperation(OperationEnum operation, double aggregateValue, 
                                double sourceValue)
{
    if (operation == OperationEnum.Sum)
        return aggregateValue + sourceValue;
    if (operation == OperationEnum.Subtract)
        return aggregateValue - sourceValue;
    if (operation == OperationEnum.Multiply)
        return aggregateValue * sourceValue;
    if (operation == OperationEnum.Divide)
        return aggregateValue / sourceValue;
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported Aggregation Operation");
}
```

It seems very repetitive.  Is there a way to generalize this?  So I don't have to have 4 lines that are the same except a different sign?

(Note: if there is a better way that does not use the `OperationEnum` that is great)

Comment: It's a small thing, but I like to put the string value of the unsupported enum option in the exception so it's obvious what value isn't being handled.

Comment: Where are you getting the OperationEnum from?

Comment: You sure you don't want OOP here? inheritance?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I made it.  It can be seen here if you want: https://gist.github.com/790434  I did not include it in the question because I did not want to clutter it.

Comment: @RQDQ, there might not be a string representation. Presumably, the enum has only those four options. You're not restricted to actually *using* one of those options when using the enum. For example, you could write `(OperationEnum)17`.

Comment: I think the question is more along the lines of, is this operation argument value coming from a UI, a database, etc (or at least that's my question)

Comment: @Anthony Pegram, agreed, but throwing a operation.ToString() into the exception would provide some insight.

Comment: @Vaccano - The reason I ask is that if you're stuck with taking an OperationEnum, you won't be able to simplify this much further, but if you can change the way the method works, there might be more you can do. We'd need to see how you're using the method, though (i.e. how you're coming up with the OperationEnum value).

Comment: @StriplingWarror - I plan to read it in from an xml file.  Right now I have it hard coded in my code (I just am calling it with OperationEnum.Sum)

Comment: +1 Liked question occasionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks about right to me, although I'd use a `switch` statement for this. But maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do?

```
switch(operation)
{
    case OperationEnum.Sum:      return aggregateValue + sourceValue;
    case OperationEnum.Subtract: return aggregateValue - sourceValue;
    case OperationEnum.Multiply: return aggregateValue * sourceValue;
    case OperationEnum.Divide:   return aggregateValue / sourceValue;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported Aggregation Operation");
}
```

It's essentially the same, but at least it looks prettier.

Comment: Please explain why this was downvoted. It's possible that I didn't understand what OP wanted, but the question seems to be asking for improvements to the code block he posted. Without more information about his situation, prettifying the code seems like the only thing to do here. I clearly wasn't the only person who thought so, either. Perhaps the question needs to be more specific. Either way, a downvote with no explanation helps no one.

Comment: +1 - though this doesn't solve the repetitiveness, at least it's more readable and can be optimized by the compiler to use a `Hashtable` internally if there are many case statements.

Comment: Internally works at assembly level exacly the same as in question

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: Not necessarily. The compiler will choose an intelligent implementation depending on the values assigned to the enum fields. This could end up using the same implementation as in the question, but it's likely that it will choose an even faster implementation. @Justin Morgan: Only reason I didn't upvote this is that @lasseespeholt beat you to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `Dictionary<OperationEnum, Func<double, double, double>>`:

```
static readonly Dictionary<OperationEnum, Func<double, double, double>> operations = 
    new Dictionary<OperationEnum, Func<double, double, double>> {
        { OperationEnum.Sum, (a, b) => a + b },
        ...
    };
```

Comment: as far as I know `Func` generic type accepts only 2 types: `public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg)`

Comment: @Elalfer No, `Func` takes from 2 to 17 (16 inputs and 1 output) types :)

Comment: @Filip Is it more generalized by doing the same (more or less) repetitive code with constructing a dictionary?

Comment: Depends, I'd rather do like @SLaks showed than having a lot of ifs. Maybe it's just my personal opinion though.

Comment: @lasseespeholt Ok, but it doesn't written in the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: This doesn't really generalize anything, since you'd still need to manually enter the entries...

Comment: @Elalfer If you press System a level up, you see a long list of objects etc. where there is ~16 Func. Your link is to one specific version.

Comment: @Elalfer, I'm curious at your comments here in light of the very answer you posted. What did you think your `return operators[operation](aggregateValue, sourceValue)` was actually going to do, if not invoke a `Func<double, double, double>`?

Comment: @SLaks: Dictionary<,> accessor works mush slower than List<> accessor, despite your rating, though ;)

Comment: @Artur: +1... mush, mush slower indeed. :]

Comment: @Mehrdad: I do not eat mushrooms, but from your point of view, you can probably disagree, then ;) I'm thinking of a new keyboard ;) ....

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of delegates, so your function will look something like:

```
private double PerformOperation(OperationEnum operation, double aggregateValue, 
                            double sourceValue)
{
    return operators[operation](aggregateValue, sourceValue);
}
```

Comment: But this requires that you build the dictionary which makes it longer and maybe more unreadable than the current solution or a switch.

Comment: But it will be more "reusable" code, and sometimes less code doesn't mean better.

Comment: `return operators[operation](aggregateValue, sourceValue)` - what is it returning? what is `operators`?

Comment: @Elalfer I would really like to understand your logic and improve my knowledge, as I have seen this approach work in various places. But in this case the asker still have to use `PerformOperation` and therefore it is not far from a switch (converts to array loopup). Maybe you think about the possibility to add features on runtime with this solution?

Comment: @VoodooChild As I said `dictionary of delegates`, and it should be quite easy to figure out how must it look like

Comment: I prefer the switch statements for enums, as the compiler will intelligently choose the fastest strategy (array, dictionary, or iterative) depending on the switch cases. If you wanted to make your operation list "extensible", the dictionary strategy can come in handy, but if you're switching on an enum you know at compile time exactly how many possible values there are and what you're going to do with each one.

Comment: @lasseespeholt At the end you can just get rid of `PerformOperation` method and just use `operators[operation](aggregateValue, sourceValue)` in your code if you need it.

Comment: @Elafer: ok, you should edit your answer more to show a workable example related to the question. So in future someone can reference this post, because as it stands now - some of us might have difficulty figuring out this approach.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior First of all question was `how to generalize`, and second, I'm not sure about performance. There are no strategy for `switch` or a lot of `if` and every wrong `if` will cause CPU mu-op cache clear. But if you create an array of delegates it could be even faster and looks nicer

Comment: @Elalfer Sure, but you need ~10 lines of code to build the dictionary and I (subjective) prefer calling a method like `PerformOperation` rather than use `operators[operation](aggregateValue, sourceValue)` in my code various places. By using `PerformOperation` the implementation details are hidden which allow me to replace the algorithms. I respect your opinion, though :)

Comment: @lassee, you need at most 5 lines of code to construct this dictionary. See SLaks answer for reference. Think 1 line for declaration, 4 lines for loading the `Func<,,>` values. Is it more readable? Your call.

Comment: @Anthony ~10 lines with new lines for brackets etc. The 5 line feat can also be done with a switch, see Justin' answer.

Comment: Agree with Anthony. This is another reason why ppl prefer to write class factories instead of huge switches and use other templates, because it is supportable, reusable and quite easy to read.

Comment: dictionary of delegates works too slow than array access by index

Comment: @Artur Read all my comments and you'll find `an array of delegates it could be even faster and looks nicer`

Comment: @Elalfer: I don't really see how this is "generalizing" the code, since you'll still need just as much repetitive code to populate the dictionary, as in SLaks's answer. Regarding performance, it is incorrect to say "there are no strategy for `switch`."  The compiler will choose the best strategy, and use either a jump table, a binary decision tree, a dictionary, or a series of if/else statements depending on the case statements and the numeric values of each of the enum fields. With only 4 possible values, even if/else statements will be faster than a dictionary lookup.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: +1 -- 500% agree. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `List<Func<double, double, double>>`:

`List<T>` accessor works mush faster than Dictionary<> accessor, and comparable to switch statement ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        enum OperationEnum : int { Sum, Muiltiply, Divide, Subtract }
        static List<Func<double, double, double>> actions = new List<Func<double, double, double>>()
        {
            { (a,b) => a+b },
            { (a,b) => a*b },
            { (a,b) => a/b },
            { (a,b) => a-b },
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", actions[(int)OperationEnum.Sum](1, 3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, it's a possible solution though, doesn't deserve a down-vote.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, @Artur Mustafin: First of all, I wasn't the one who down-voted it. Secondly, the "solution" at the time I wrote my comment was not an answer to the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4763840/revisions

Comment: I hear you say a lot stuff about my solution not being short enough. But what happens to your solution if I do this `enum OperationEnum : int { Sum, Muiltiply = 0, ... }`? This means you would also have to use the 4 different `OperationEnum.X` somewhere like SLaks' solution. By the way, I haven't downvoted your answer - I'm just expressing my opinion on your solution (which is indeed a solution).

Comment: @lasseespeholt: If you do that, nothing will change at all, think about it. My solution will break, if any, at the same point as yours, if you will play with enums, moreover, i just initialized the list in declarative manner only for shortage, so if you think twice, you will understand, that you solution and mine are almost the same, but i eliminated the excessiveness, and you don't ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nope... it's not quite that generalizable, although I wish it was too. :\

Comment: This should have been a comment. Just because you don't have any concrete answers to the problem, doesn't mean there aren't any.

Comment: But the fact of the matter is that *somewhere* you need to manually match the signs with the enum members by hand (it's not like the compiler does that). There's simply no way to avoid that, so there's no way to generalize this more.

Comment: ... how? Isn't it a fact? Do you have any better idea?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: In addition to what Mehrdad said, it appears you also down-voted everybody who tried to provide a concrete answer, but failed to make it more general. I would rather have an "it can't be done" answer (if it can't be done) or a "you can improve it like so" answer than to have no answers at all.

Comment: @Filip: The question was quite literally " **Is** there a way to generalize this?" And so I don't get why an answer of "No" is bad or argumentative in any way.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I've up-voted the answers that I like and down-voted the ones that I don't think contribute anything to this thread. @Mehrdad, there are ways to generalize it, as others have proven. The question is if it is possible to generalize operations **like** this, and it is possible. Therefore I think your answer should be left as a comment instead.

Comment: "This is impossible" is still an answer. If it's correct, it's a useful answer, because the questioner can save time trying to do the futile. I've seen such answers be upvoted, accepted, and appreciated. If he's wrong, that might deserve a downvote, but he should be proven wrong first.

Comment: @Filip: No, the question was "generalize this" and **not** "generalize operations like this". You misread it apparently, and downvoted everyone for not answering a different question. Also, you should realize that "questions like this" is *way* more subjective and vague than my answer is "argumentative".

Comment: @Justin, sure there are times when the answer "No" might be correct. But methods to make it more general have been provided, therefore I don't think this answer deserves any upvotes. @Mehrdad, I meant that the question is argumentative. Not your answer.

Comment: @Filip: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643465/writing-a-cross-platform-32-bit-and-64-bit-compatible-program-for-windows-like) as an example of something whose answer was, simply, "this is not possible" (paraphrased), but that I completely liked and accepted, and that was upvoted.

Comment: @Mehrdad, yes but that answer had a bit more information in it than "It's not possible".

Comment: @Filip: (a) That's because the reason for the answer wasn't as straightforward as here. In this question, there simply *isn't any feature that permits more generalization*... there's not much to elaborate on. (b) I'd have accepted that question anyway even if all it said was "No; mscoree.dll is the .NET loader and not the framework."... I don't care if the answer is long or short, but whether or not it was to the point. (c) No one asked that you upvote anything (I can see why you wouldn't upvote this answer), but we were all just surprised why you downvoted the answers.

Comment: Ok, I've stated why I think you deserve a down-vote, I shouldn't have to explain myself. If you answer with no "proof" of why it isn't possible, it's impossible to take this answer serious. I've up-voted three of the answers I liked here and down-voted one or two that I didn't like.

Comment: @Filip: How can you "prove" that something doesn't exist?!?!? Do you want me to refer the OP to the entire hundreds of pages of the ECMA C# specification and "prove" it to him by telling him to read them, and observe that no solution exists?!

Comment: @Mehrdad, Appearently someone succeded to do that in the thread you linked. Maybe saying "No it is not possible to generalize this more because you would need to store the operators in a dictionary that would defeat the purpose of generalization. It would lead to as much code no matter what you do". Something like that maybe?

Comment: @Filip: Well, maybe my answer doesn't deserve an up-vote, but does it really deserve a *downvote*? It wasn't wrong or misleading, and from what I've observed on SO, you need to downvote things that spread misinformation, *not* things that you "don't like".

Comment: We have different point of views on what to up-/down-vote. You upvote something that you want to put weight on, that provides something good to the thread. The opposite for down-voting. Instead of argumenting here weather or not your answer deserves a down-/up-vote, why not spend the time answering questions instead? :)

Comment: "Above all, be honest. If you see **misinformation**, vote it down. *Add comments* indicating what, specifically, is wrong. **Provide better answers of your own**. Best of all — *edit* and **improve** the existing questions and answers!" (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Mehrdad, I think your question is misinformation. And I've told you why I think so. Appearently someone else thought the same.. It's up to every individual to up-/down-vote the answers that they do/don't like. I don't see why you take it so personally. Eventually if you have to argument on Every down-vote, no one is going to use them and they become pointless.

Comment: @Filip: I don't take it personally (honestly, I up-voted one of your comments on another thread about half an hour ago!! I didn't take it personally :) ) but if I really spread misinformation, I want to know, so both I and others can learn something. Feel free to vote however you want, but I just wanted to know why you voted how you did, so that it could actually be constructive.

Comment: I understand that, one of my comments I left contained an "example" of what I think would make the answer "better" and thus, maybe, would have deserved another voting. I rarely edit others answers more than correcting spelling errors, I rather tell the poster about it instead. :)

Comment: @Filip: Well the issue was that you only commented on it *after* I asked you... usually you should comment on it yourself, without the answerer needing to ask why you downvoted. But whatever; it's not that important... don't worry, I didn't take it personally. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad, It's just a guideline anyways in the FAQ, it's not like it's rocket science to figure out why one gets a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

A switch would be prettier at least :) and the code will be more efficient (array look-ups etc.). Furthermore, the compiler and IDE can give you some hints when you miss certain options etc.

But as stated in my comment, this isn't really an answer just general code improving.

```
switch (operation)
{
    case OperationEnum.Sum:
        return aggregateValue + sourceValue;
    case OperationEnum.Subtract:
        return aggregateValue - sourceValue;
    case OperationEnum.Multiply:
        return aggregateValue * sourceValue;
    case OperationEnum.Divide:
        return aggregateValue / sourceValue;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported Aggregation Operation");
}
```

Comment: I respect a downvote - but please state why you(?) do so - I could have a fair argument...

Comment: How is this more general than the if-setup?

Comment: @Filip Thanks :) It is not... however a switch do come with certain advantages from the IDE and the compiled code itself. But I see your point and this isn't really an answer but something that should go in a comment - I'll consider deleting this answer...

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Internally it works at assembly level exacly the same as in question

Comment: @Artur It will properly be optimized to the same array lookup (if that is the fastest solution) in this case but at least I know that will happen with the switch because a switch is very strict and therefore the compiler can reason about it easier. In the general case you can't know for sure because a compiler can't know what you precisely are doing when we speak of turing-complete languages.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Still thinks, that { (a,b) => a+b } is much more readable ,than case OperationEnum.Sum: return aggregateValue + sourceValue;

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: `{ (a,b) => a+b }` is shorter, but I don't find it more readable, and it's prone to break without any compiler warnings if there is ever a change to the OperationEnum class (e.g. if the fields are reordered).

Comment: @Artur, if you like I can change the parameter names ;) that leaves me with `OperationEnum.Plus: return a + b`;

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, however, I believe a switch statement would be the more efficient.

```
private double Evaluate(string expression)
{
    return (double)new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument
    (new System.IO.StringReader("<r/>")).CreateNavigator().Evaluate
    (string.Format("number({0})", new
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([\+\-\*])")
    .Replace(expression, " ${1} ")
    .Replace("/", " div ").Replace("%", " mod ")));
}
```

OR

```
private double Evaluate(string expression)
{
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("expression", string.Empty.GetType(), expression);
    System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    return double.Parse((string)row["expression"]);
}
```

Then...

```
public double PerformOperation(double x, double y, string op)
    {
        string exp = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}"
                    , x.ToString()
                    , op, y.ToString());

        return Evaluate(exp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the context of this, but rather than the enum you could use a delegate that performs the desired operation to be passed into your "PerformOperation"-method. However you probably don't even need that static method if you would use this approach. Another benefit is that you don't have to care about the special case where the operation is not supported, any operation is supported. Here's a quick example:

```
namespace Example
{
    using System;

    public delegate double Operation(double first, double second);

    public static class Operations
    {
        public static readonly Operation Sum = (first, second) => first + second;
        public static readonly Operation Subtract = (first, second) => first - second;
        public static readonly Operation Multiply = (first, second) => first * second;
        public static readonly Operation Divide = (first, second) => first / second;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double seed = 0;
            double aggregateValue = 0;

            aggregateValue = PerformOperation(Operations.Sum, 5, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(aggregateValue);

            aggregateValue = PerformOperation(Operations.Multiply, aggregateValue, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(aggregateValue);

            aggregateValue = PerformOperation(Operations.Subtract, aggregateValue, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(aggregateValue);

            aggregateValue = PerformOperation(Operations.Divide, aggregateValue, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(aggregateValue);

            // You can even pass delegates to other methods with matching signatures,
            // here to get the power of ten.
            aggregateValue = PerformOperation(Math.Pow, aggregateValue, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(aggregateValue);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static double PerformOperation(Operation operation, double aggregateValue, double sourceValue)
        {
            return operation(aggregateValue, sourceValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this approach you can easily extend your program with new operations without even touching the PerformOperation-method. This can be taken quite a few steps further but without knowing the context it's hard to describe.